# SP.RequestExecutor is undefined for angular controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is a sharepoint hosted app where I am trying to use the Sharepoint Request Executor to make a REST API Call to the host web to get list items.

The code is however failing on the file:
`datacontext.angular.js` on the line:

```
 var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(spContext.hostWeb.appWebUrl);
```

When I check the debugger it looks like SP does not have a RequestExecutor 
constructor.

Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/EWasAvaDKaHs

The relevant code is as follows:

**fases.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // define controller
    var controllerId = "fases";
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
      ['$location', '$routeParams', 'common', 'datacontext', 'spContext' , fases]);

    // create controller
    function fases($location, $routeParams, common, datacontext, spContext) {
        var vm = this;

        // navigate to the specified item
        vm.gotoItem = gotoItem;
        // build link to create new learning items
        vm.newfaseItemUrl = newfaseItemUrl;

        // init controller
        init();

        // load all learning items
        getFases();

        function newfaseItemUrl() {
            var faseId = +$routeParams.learningPathId || 0;

            if (faseId && faseId > 0) {
                return '#/Fases/' + faseId + '/Items/new';
            } else {
                return '#/Fases/new';
            }
        }

        // navigate to the specified item
        function gotoItem(faseItem) {
            if (faseItem && faseItem.Id) {
                $location.path('/Fases/' + faseItem.Id);
            }
        }

        // #region private memebers
        // init controller
        function init() {
            common.logger.log("controller loaded", null, controllerId);
            common.activateController([], controllerId);
        }

        // gets all learning items as partials (filtered if specified)
        function getFases() {
            // get the fase  to filter on
            // if not specified, this comes back as NaN which is 
            // dealt with in the datacontext
            var faseId = +$routeParams.faseId;

            var scriptbase = spContext.hostWeb.url + '/_layouts/15/';
            $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js',
               function () {
                   $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js',
                       function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', datacontext.getFasesPartials(faseId)); }
                   );
               }
           );

            datacontext.getFasesPartials(faseId)
              .then(function (data) {
                  if (data) {
                      vm.fases = data;
                  } else {
                      throw new Error('Error al obtener los datos');
                  }
              }).catch(function (error) {
                  common.logger.logError('Error al obtener las fases', error, controllerId);
              });
        }
    };

})();
```

**datacontext.angular.js**

```
/*
 * datacontext that uses the Anuglar $http service
 */

(function () {
  'use strict';

  // define factory
  var serviceId = 'datacontext';
  angular.module('app').factory(serviceId,
    ['$rootScope', '$http', '$resource', '$q', 'config', 'common', 'spContext', datacontext]);

  function datacontext($rootScope, $http, $resource, $q, config, common, spContext) {
    // init factory
    init();

    // service public signature
    return {
        //Get all items on the Fases list
        getFasesPartials: getFasesPartials,

    };

    // init service
    function init() {
      common.logger.log("service loaded", null, serviceId);
    }

    // retrieve all learning paths, usingngHttp service
    function getFasesPartials() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // executor: The RequestExecutor object
      // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
      var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(spContext.hostWeb.appWebUrl);

      // Issue the call against the app web.
      // To get the title using REST we can hit the endpoint:
        //       appweburl / _api / web / lists / getbytitle('listname') / items
      // The response formats the data in the JSON format.
      // The functions successHandler and errorHandler attend the
      // sucess and error events respectively.
      executor.executeAsync(
          {
              url: spContext.hostWeb.appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('FasesPrueba')/items?@target='" + spContext.hostWeb.url ,
              method: "GET",
              headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
              success: successHandler,
              error: errorHandler
          }
      );

      // Function to handle the success event.
      // Prints the data to the page.
      function successHandler(data) {
          var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
          deferred.resolve(jsonObject.d.results);
      }

      // Function to handle the error event.
      // Prints the error message to the page.
      function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
          var message = "data context ngHttp error: " + error.message;
          common.logger.logError(message, error, serviceId);
          deferred.reject(error);
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    }

  }
})();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should reference the `SP.RequestExecutor.js` before the `angular.js` reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```